# Adding ScriptResourceMapping named jquery to customer site

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, scriptmanager, asp.net-4.5

On my development PC in Visual Studio 2012 and on the customer site I added the following setting to the web.config:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

I added jquery and jquery.validate scripts to the aspx pages. I also added to the global.asax.cs in the method Application_start the code:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
   {
      Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js",
      DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js",
      CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
      CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
    });
```

Everything works on my development PC as far as validation; no error. But on the customer site I get the error:

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a  ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

The Global.asax is included in the project.  Why on the customer site I get the error? what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using **ASP.NET 4.5** here. I believe that you need to try changing your AppSettings key to:

```
   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Please refer to this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

Comment: Landsteven, I know about the option of "none."  But in my testing in VS 2012 validating didn't work. So I need to enable UnobstrusiveValidationMode.  I just don't understand why the ScriptReouseMapping I added to Global.asax does not work on the customer site.

Comment: Have you tried to Recycle the App Pool after making this change to the application?

Comment: No, I have not Recycled the App Pool. I will have to learn how to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: I found what was the problem.  I didn't deploy the Global.asax to the customer site. Sorry :).